# How to free/release Joomla db connection after the Query execute?

Tags: joomla

Below are my code lines

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query =$db->getQuery(true);
    $query ->select('id')
           ->from($db->quoteName('#_menu'))
           ->where('alias'. "=" ."'about'".'AND published = 1');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

how to release db connection after query execution ?

Comment: What do you mean by "release" the connection?

Comment: In Java we have option to close the connection after query executing ,for example in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection

Answer (score 0):

Trying to close the connection in Joomla is pointless because the core and even 3rd party extensions that call `JFactory::getDbo();` so it will be reopened.

If you really need to, then you can use `$db->disconnect();` which basically calls `mysqli_close()` or the equivalent to whatever database drive you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Although i suppose after each query the database connection gets closed. Still there are two methods that can be used

1. If you want to close or disconnect the database session, you can
   use:

   $db->disconnect();  Ref:
   http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_disconnect
2. You can also use this instead after a query result is passed to a
   Variable:

   $db->freeResult(); Ref :
   http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriverMysql.html#method_freeResult

Comment: Pretty much a copy and paste of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25914199/1362108

Comment: @Lodder Entire stackoverflow answers are a copy paste of some page. php.net site has all the answers of many php questions here. Even walking, eating, drinking is copy paste of what elders did.